# pathauto patterns showing an empty page drupal 7

Tags: 7, path-aliases, version-control

When loading admin/config/search/path/patterns no content/form is showing up.
Is there any way to show up the content of the patterns...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to flush the site's cache ? Sometimes it just reapear by magic (It happened to me on building a big corporation site).

Another lead in drupal.org, they seems to think that is a "php value memory_limit" problem : https://www.drupal.org/node/1267966

Answer (score 0):

Flushing all caches solved it for me, thanks :)